# post serialized data through using jquery load method in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my code.

```
 <form id='user'>
   <label for="name">Name :</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
   <label for="email">Email :</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
 <div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#user').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data=$(this).serialize();
        adddetails(data);
});
function adddetails(data){
        var url='http://localhost/projectname/index.php/users/adddat';
        $("#output").load(url,data,function(response,status){
        });
}
```

In the 'users' controller

```
function adddat(){
    $name=$this->input->post('name');
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    echo "name: ".$name." and email: ".$email;
}
```

Here when I click on submit the output div is shown like this

`name:  and email:`

Here I am not getting the post data of name and email. Could anyone suggest me an idea.

Comment: Please check console the value is passed to your page on that page you need to unserialize

Comment: @Ramki The data doesn't pass to the controller method.

Comment: Try with `$this->input->get('name');`

Comment: What do you see on console.log(data) within your .on('submit') block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**serialize** method create a string output. to Make a POST call you need to use JSON object.

```
$('#user').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data=formToJSON('#user');
        adddetails(data);
});
function adddetails(data){
        var url='http://localhost/projectname/index.php/users/adddat';
        $("#output").load(url,data,function(response,status){
        });
}


function formToJSON( selector )
{
     var form = {};
     $(selector).find(':input[name]:enabled').each( function() {
         var self = $(this);
         var name = self.attr('name');
         if (form[name]) {
            form[name] = form[name] + ',' + self.val();
         }
         else {
            form[name] = self.val();
         }
     });

     return form;
}
```

Credit [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery])

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery's load function ([JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method))

> POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Per JQuery's definition of the [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

That said, you're attempting to get a POST variable when GET is assumed, as it's not an object being passed to the `load` function, it's a string.

Try using
    `$this->input->get('parameter_name')`

As a sidenote, you may be able to get the data points as function parameters: `function addat($name, $email){` as codeigniter usually will accept that method of getting GET params.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. using get request instead of post solves the problem.